# Why this wildcard works?

Tags: java, generics

I am confused with this code, which is supposed not to work (I guess), but it seems to work with no errors.

When I put `<T>` next to class Person, the wildcard in Arraylist don't behave as it is defined, in the code below, the wildcard should only work for `super` Person class, but with the `<T>` next to the class Person, it accept all kind for types (in this example it's `String`). And also for this to work, Human when defined should not have the type specified. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Person {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Human h = new Human();
        h.al(new ArrayList<String>()); // this should give an error no ?
    }
}

class Human<T>{ //Human is a generic class, but above I created an instance without specifying the T
    public void al(ArrayList<? super Person> a){ //the type passed should be a super of Person

    }
}
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is answered in the Java Generics FAQ: [Can I use a raw type like any other type?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ203)

The answer says:

> Methods or constructors of a raw type have the signature that they would have after type erasure.

In English, it means that because you declared `h` as a raw type `Human`, the compiler will perform [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens) on `h` and the effective signature of the `al` method is actually the one after the type erasure! So as far as the compiler can tell, your code is sane.

Also see the answers to this question: [Java generics - type erasure - when and what happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)
 for some more examples.

Wikipedia also has a good section on some of the [Problems with Type erasures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure) that might be tricky to catch.

**UPDATE**

The snippet below will throw a ClassCastException at runtime.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

class Human<T>{
  public void al(ArrayList<? super Person> a){
    Iterator<? super Person> iter = a.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
      Person h = (Person) iter.next(); // unsafe cast
    }
  }
}

public class Person {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Human h = new Human();

    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    arr.add("deadbeef");

    h.al(arr); // valid, since h is raw
  }
}
```

Comment: The eraser causes a unchecked warning, but this is at compile time no ? What about runtime, shouldn't it cause an error when running the program ?

Comment: Yes, it can cause an exception at runtime. But that depends on what the code really does. I updated the answer with an example. Thanks.

Comment: @Amir, What kind of "details" are you looking for?

Comment: John thank you for your answer, I opened a bounty for this question to find a more detailed explanation, but your answer is the best for now.

Comment: It's not really clear what more detailed explanation you need. The erasure of `Human.al` is `public void al(ArrayList a)`...

Answer (score 0):

If you use a generic parametrised class without `<>` the generic typing is disabled for that class, for that variable.
If you do:

```
Human<Object> h = new Human<>();
```

then a compiler error would be raised.

Comment: AFAIK <> diamond operator is a part of java 7, Link to the Original Proposal http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-February/000009.html So the compile error would not occur for the version 1.7 and up.

Comment: The diamond operator is irrelevant here, pre-1.7 you could write `Human<Object> human = new Human<Object>();` with the same result.

Comment: @Landei thanks for the clarification: indeed the problem here is having `Human h` instead of `Human<Object>`.

Comment: Yes if you specify the type `<T>` the warning disappear, but my question is why it disappear ? What is the rule I'm missing ?